# Set mailto from codebehind (or front-end)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have to following html code:

`Email:&nbsp;<a href="mailto:...?subject=subject"><asp:Label style="margin-right: 90px;" ID="EmailLabel" 
                               CssClass="InfoData" runat="server" Text="E-mail"></asp:Label></a>`Email:  ``

as seen in the  tag, I have a mailto. I need to add an email at the mailto, but this email will vary, so I can't hard code it. I am getting it from the database, so I do have it already, but how will I add it in the html code as a variable?

All the examples found have emails hardcoded in the mailto:

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to control the value server-side, then I suggest using a server control, like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
               NavigateUrl="mailto:abc@abc.com" 
               Text="abc@abc.com">
</asp:HyperLink>
```

`NavigateUrl` and `Text` are the properties you will want to interact with in the code-behind, like this:

```
// Get values from database
string emailAddress = GetEmailFromDatabase();
string subject = GetSubjctFromDatabase();

// Set NavigateUrl to use email address and subject values from above
HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "mailto:" + emailAddress + "?subject=" + subject;

// You can also set the text of the hyper link here or in the markup
HyperLink1.Text = "Send email to " + emailAddress;
```

---

> Note: The markup has a `NavigateUrl` value set, but you can remove it from the markup or just leave it, as the code-behind will overwrite it. I was just showing that the property exists, not trying to confuse you with hardcoding a value.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your markup:

```
<a id="mailtoLink" href="" runat="server">email</a>
```

In your code behind:

```
mailtoLink.Attributes["href"] = "mailto:a@a.com";
```

Answer (score 2):

In your aspx

set your anchor's href to href=<%=destinationEmail%>

Code-behind in your class (not inside a method)

public string destinationEmail = "mailto:test@test.com";

You can then change destinationEmail to whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a literal control:

```
<asp:Literal id="emailLiteral" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

And for the code behind:

```
string emailColumn = YourGetEmailMethod()
emailLiteral.Text = "<a href=""mailto:" + emailColumn + """>Send mail to" + emailColumn + "</a>"
```